# Menu Icon in App Bar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

So I was wondering how I create a menu that pops up on the left side when someone clicks the menu icon on the app bar. Just to be clear I am talking about the appbar with buttons. Here's the code for it:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import AppBar from '@material-ui/core/AppBar';
import Toolbar from '@material-ui/core/Toolbar';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';

const styles = {
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  flex: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
  menuButton: {
    marginLeft: -12,
    marginRight: 20,
  },
};

function ButtonAppBar(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <AppBar position="static">
        <Toolbar>
          <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
            <MenuIcon /> //I want a menu to pop up on the left-side when someone clicks this button
          </IconButton>
          <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
            News
          </Typography>
          <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
}

ButtonAppBar.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(ButtonAppBar);
```

Comment: What is your question/problem?

Comment: I want a menu to pop from the left side when someone clicks the menu icon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can have a parent component that is class based (which has all states and handlers baked in) then you can have a navigation component and sidebar component (both should be stateless component; based on usage of yours) then by clicking  on a button on navigation you should change the corresponding state on the parent component; then you should chain the visibility of your sidebar component based on that state.

actually i just took a moment and created what you need here, just a simple example...
https://codesandbox.io/s/m86ko7vp

for adding animations you can use `react-motion` or `react-spring`

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful, if i were to make sidebar a class based component and give it it's own state, would this still work?

Comment: by that , you would put yourself in a lot of plumbing , sidebar should get a value to make itself visible based on that, and that is why we have a parent component to keep all state of those component , instead of having multiple class based components and wiring them together

Comment: I want it so that if a user logs in the sidebar would display different information so  I would need the side bar to have a state. Would incorporating Redux and having a global state make this easier to manage?

Comment: yes but for that i think you need to have some sort of authentication stuff like the example that is on  `react-router-v4` website , redux is always is a helpful tool feel free to use it if your project is going to grow....

Answer (score 1):

You can add multiple Icon in app bar on either side and should mention the action when the icon is clicked,try these steps and get menu or search icon in the app bar.

Source:
[Add search and menu in app bar](https://youtu.be/Lnzu-1sH108)